# Advanced Search with PHP, AJAX and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, select

I am creating an advanced search, where a user can select(html select) a category (which filters the results with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`) and then they can type into an input to find results using `LIKE` with multiple columns in the db.

I'm getting no errors, however is not returning the correct data the select(html) returns unrelated results and the input returns nothing, therefore, I'm pretty sure the issue is with my SQL query in candidate_search.php

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" class="serach_form" method="post">
    <select id="" name="cv_category" class="cv_category">
        <option value="category1">category 1 </option>
        <option value="category2">category 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="search" class="search_input" placeholder="Search" />
</form>
```

**AJAX:**

```
$('.serach_form').change(function() {
    var $search_input = $('.search_input').val();
    var $cv_category = $('.cv_category').val();
    var url = "candidate_search.php";
    $.ajax({
        //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "POST", 
        url: url, 
        data:{
            search_input: $search_input, cv_category: $cv_category
        },  
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(date) {
            $('#search_data').html(date);
        }
    })
});
```

**PHP: (candidate_search.php)**

```
<?php 
include 'db_connect.php';
$search_input = $_POST['search_input'];
$cv_category = $_POST['cv_category'];
if(isset($search_input) || (isset($cv_category))){
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidates_table WHERE full_name LIKE :search_input AND phone_number LIKE :search_input AND email_address LIKE :search_input AND id LIKE :search_input GROUP BY cv_category HAVING :cv_category");
    $sql->bindValue(':search_input', '%' . $search_input . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindValue(':cv_category', '%' . $cv_category . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if($sql->execute()) {
        $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    while($row = $sql->fetch()) { 
        // Do something ..... //
    } // End of whileloop //
} // end of isset // ?>
```

Comment: Hi bob , since you are using ajax are you echoing the output ?.

Comment: @NishantNair Sorry, I just saw your comment, I'm returning the data into a div on AJAX success function.  In the while loop I have the html structure and within that I'm echoing the data in php.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can try to debug the steps:

first debug with var_dump(name_of_variable); die();

the receive values from the browser, if its ok, your request

- Try to execute directly in MySQL to see the result
- Debug your PDO prepare and bindValue
- And your request should use OR not AND condition like

  - `SELECT * FROM candidates_table WHERE full_name LIKE :search_input OR phone_number LIKE :search_input OR email_address LIKE :search_input OR id LIKE :search_input GROUP BY cv_category HAVING :cv_category`

And don't forget to return JSON or XML not an array ( throw error ).

Hope it will help you !

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming `full_name` and `phone_number` are text fields?
Why are you using `like` when you can do an equal to?

```
SELECT * FROM candidates_table WHERE full_name = :search_input OR phone_number = :search_input OR email_address = :search_input OR id = :search_input GROUP BY cv_category HAVING :cv_category"
```

Also why are you using `HAVING`?
HAVING clause is used to do a filter for aggregate queries like sum or average or similar.  I don't think you want that.

If you only want to get the values when search term is exactly equal to the value in the db then I would suggest you use the `=` rather than `like`.

Looking at the javascript I can see that you want to continuously lookup every time the form changes.  You would want to do partial text matches as well.  In this case you should use wildcards to match the value.  Use `%` before and after the search term.  If the search string is a substring of the value in the DB, it would return a result.

Also I would replace the having query with an and operation.  Pleas check the following code:

**Here is the query:**

I would use this query instead of the one you are using.

```
"SELECT * FROM candidates_table WHERE (full_name like '%:search_input%' OR phone_number = '%:search_input%' OR email_address = '%:search_input%' OR id = '%:search_input%') AND cv_category = :cv_category"
```

PS: I would also recommend you explore another data source other than MySQL.  Like queries are slow in MySQL.

----EDIT----

```
<?php 
include 'db_connect.php';
$search_input = $_POST['search_input'];
$cv_category = $_POST['cv_category'];
if(isset($search_input) || (isset($cv_category))){
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidates_table WHERE (full_name like '%:full_name%' OR phone_number = '%:phone_number%' OR email_address = '%:email_address%' OR id = '%:id%') AND cv_category = :cv_category"
);
    $sql->bindValue(':full_name', '%' . $search_input . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindValue(':phone_number', '%' . $search_input . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindValue(':email_address', '%' . $search_input . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindValue(':id', '%' . $search_input . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindValue(':cv_category', '%' . $cv_category . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if($sql->execute()) {
        $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    while($row = $sql->fetch()) { 
        // Do something ..... //
    } // End of whileloop //
} // end of isset // ?>
```

Comment: I was doing `%` when i was binding the value, talking about binding the value how many would i have, technical I only have two variables, but I'm using one more than once. But mysql doesn't like two. I get ` Invalid parameter number` error

Comment: Why do you want to use the same name to bind it?

Comment: `search_input ` is going through multiple columns to find a match.

Comment: Check edit.  All params binded to the same variable.

Comment: I still get the same error message of  `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

Answer (score 0):

The search query should be always with `OR` operator, like this:

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidates_table WHERE full_name LIKE :search_input OR phone_number LIKE :search_input OR email_address LIKE :search_input OR id LIKE :search_input GROUP BY cv_category HAVING :cv_category");
```

Comment: this sql statement is not save to use. SQL injection ca easily be done

Comment: @NishantNair I am not adding any SQL injection protection, I am making the query right only.

Comment: @Pathik Vejani I tried `OR` before however same result.

Comment: @bob just try that query in mysql and see is the result you want? also you need to echo the output.

Comment: @Pathik Vejani I tried it now, just in case. and same result.

Comment: Exactly what was in your answer: `$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidates_table WHERE full_name LIKE :search_input OR phone_number LIKE :search_input OR email_address LIKE :search_input OR id LIKE :search_input GROUP BY cv_category HAVING :cv_category");`

Comment: @bob what is the need for `having`?

Comment: There is a column called `cv_category` which gives each row a category, I'm using a html select for a user to choose all the rows that belong to a category.